# Symfony2 - target-entity cannot be found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

These are the entities:

**Objective.php**

```
namespace Foo\BSCBundle\Entity;

class Objective{

    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $perspective;
    ...   
}
```

**Objective.orm.yml**

```
Foo\BSCBundle\Entity\Objective:
    type: entity
    table: master.objectives
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
    manyToOne:
        perspective:
            targetEntity: Pespective
            inversedBy: objectives
            joinColumn:
                name: perspective_id
                referencesColumn: id
```

**Perspective.php**

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
namespace Foo\BSCBundle\Entity;



class Perspective {
    protected $id;
    protected $objectives;
    ...   
}
```

**Perspective.orm.yml**

```
Foo\BSCBundle\Entity\Perspective:
    type: entity
    table: perspectives
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 100

    oneToMany:
        objectives:
            targetEntity: Objective
            mappedBy: Perspective
```

**DefaultController.php**

```
public function indexAction($name)
{
    $perspective = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('FooBSCBundle:Objective')
    ->find(1);

    $params = array('name' => $name, 'perspective' => $perspective);
    return $this->render('FooBSCBundle:Default:index.html.twig', $params);
}
```

In my browser I get the error:

> The target-entity Foo\BSCBundle\Entity\Pespective cannot be found
>   in 'Foo\BSCBundle\Entity\Objective#perspective'. 500 Internal
>   Server Error - MappingException

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a typo here : **targetEntity: Pespective**

Comment: And why are you using the Objective repository to find a perspective object?